# Why does CSS render differentlyt between `npm run dev` vs `npm run build`?

Tags: css, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a simple(ish) VueJs (2.5.2) app with a dependency on vuetify (1.5.6). Project was created using Vue cli via IntelliJ, so it's a standard structure.

There is only 1 component in the app, with scoped css like this:

```
<style scoped>
 .app-stores{
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
 }

 .app-stores img{
  max-width: 190px;
 }  

 .padded-checkout-btn {
  padding: 10px;
 }
</style>
```

And then I use it in the component like so:

```
 <v-btn class="padded-checkout-btn" color="green lighten-1" :disabled="!isCheckoutable()" @click="progressStepper(2)">Checkout {{currencySymbol + toPrice(calculateTotal())}}</v-btn>
```

Now if I run `npm run dev` and view it locally in a browser, it looks as I expect with the padding:

[image: correct padding]

However if I run `npm run build` (*no* changes at all to code) and upload to a site, the padding seems to disappear:

[image: incorrect padding]

I checked the built css file and it does seem to be there:

```
.padded-checkout-btn[data-v-dedb1744]{padding:10px}
```

And if I inspect the resulting source I can see it declared there:

```
<button data-v-dedb1744="" type="button" class="padded-checkout-btn v-btn theme--light green lighten-1"><div class="v-btn__content">Checkout £7.00</div></button>
```

**Question**: Why are they different? Even if somehow the CSS is hidden, the whole point of running dev vs build is that they're the same? Any ideas as to how to diagnose/fix?

`dev` and `build` are defined like this:

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
"start": "npm run dev",
"unit": "jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js --coverage",
"test": "npm run unit",
"lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit",
"build": "node build/build.js"
}
```

Comment: could you show us the associated commands of `run` and `build` from `package.json` ?

Comment: I think the css you are having for development is not working or not present when you create the build of your project. I think it is the css not loading up.

Comment: @samb102 copy/pasted the script line from `package.json` into the post

Comment: @AKASHPANDEY i can see it in the built css file. Also the other 2 css declarations seem to work ok

Comment: But does the button have the attribute that’s in the css?

Comment: @Strelok yes it's there if when view source - updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed. Thanks to @Strelok for nudging me in the right direction. It's do with the ordering in which the css is applied. Change the declaration to:

```
.padded-checkout-btn {
  padding: 10px !important;
}
```

ensured it was applied after everything else (I guess...)

Still don't really understand why it works on Dev build and not prod build though.

Comment: its because all your css is minified when you build the production build and the position of the class overriding your class would have been below it hence overriding your css but anyways using !important should be the last resort for anything

Comment: @AKASHPANDEY the prod build *should* behave the same way; There must be a way to ensure this. Otherwise the development process is a bit flaky.